# SQL wildcards - trying to find a sequence of chars/nums within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a specific pattern within a string. The pattern is six characters (can be alpha or numeric) followed by '/' followed by three numerals.

```
ABCDEF/123
```

the following is an example of a string...

```
HMLR/MUR130/001
```

I'm trying to extract the rightmost 10 characters (they don't always appear at the end, so RIGHT() isn't and option).

I'm trying to get my head around SQL wildcards, this is what I've got so far...

```
 CHARINDEX('______/[0-9]___',Nom_details,1)
```

...but I'm not getting any results back...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a pattern expression, use `PATINDEX` instead of `CHARINDEX`. Your string example has 8 characters before the numbers.

Comment: If you need 3 numbers you need `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the index of the match, you can use [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%______/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 'HMLR/MUR130/001')
```

The function [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) doesn't support patterns.

To extract the match from data you can use `SUBSTRING` with the above `PATINDEX`:

```
WITH test (data) AS (  
    SELECT 'HMLR/MUR130/001'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABCDEF/123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'someotherstuff'
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(data, PATINDEX('%______/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', data), 10) 
FROM test
WHERE data LIKE '%______/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abe2c804fe83bf566f9ae2b111c10582)

Comment: If the six leading characters _must_ be alphanumeric then the pattern can be made more precise by replacing each of the single character wildcards (`'_'`) with `[A-Z0-9]`. (Assuming case-insensitive matching.)